# The algebra of limits - proof.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, proof-explanation

How would you prove the following theorem?

Theorem:

Let $\ell\in \mathbb{R} $ such that $(a_n) \to \ell$.

Then $p \cdot (a_n) \to p \cdot \ell $ where $p \in \mathbb{R}.$

I started out writing the definition of convergence, and the end result needed to be achieved:

Proof:

Let $\epsilon \gt 0$ be arbitrary.

So we need to show that $\exists N \in \mathbb{N} \,\, s.t. \,\, |a_n \cdot p- \ell \cdot p| \lt \epsilon \quad \forall \, n \gt N.$

We know that $(a_n) \to \ell.$
Let $p\in \mathbb{R}.$

And then I am not sure how to get $|a_n- \ell \cdot p | \lt \epsilon?$

Comment: What have you done?

Comment: I would start with writing down the definition of convergence and some basic relations between the distance function and multiplication operator.

Comment: @Ninja I have edited the question to write what I have done, not sure how to start off really. Is there a hint you could give? Cheers.

Comment: @Gurjinder No, you are trying to show that $p\cdot a_n\to p\cdot\ell$ so you need to show that $|p\cdot a_n-p\cdot \ell|<\epsilon$.

Comment: @freakish yeah, sorry, corrected- just a typo.

Comment: Just take the $|p|$paranthesis.

Answer (score 2):

For every $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists an $N \in \mathbb{N} $ such that if $n > N$ then $|a_{n} - l| < \varepsilon$.

Claim:

If $p \in \mathbb{R}$ then $\{ pa_{n}\} \to pl$. That is, for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists a $N$ such that if $n > N$ then $|pa_{n} - pl| < \varepsilon$.

Proof:

If $p = 0$, we are already done. So let $p \neq 0$. We know there exists an $N$ such that if $n > N$, then $|a_{n} - l| < \frac{\varepsilon}{|p|}$ (That fraction is a positive number). Multiplying over $|p|$, we have $|p||a_{n} - l| = |pa_{n} - pl| < \varepsilon$ and we are done.